# Crop UIImageView to bounds of parents

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView within another UIView. The UIImageView is slightly taller than the UIView. Though, I want the UIImageView to only be viewable within the UIView. Any part of the UIImageView outside of the UIView should not be seen.

I'm using a UITableView and inside the UITableViewCell will be that UIView that gives it a "card" look. As you can see below with the screenshots, the colors (red, blue, purple, green, and orange) is the background color for the cells. The UIView is the content inside the cell.

From looking only, I had to set the clipToBounds to `true` from the UIView. I did that, and the sample view from storyboard seemed to work.

[image]

The images inside the "What is truth?" UIView and "About Us" UIView crop the image correctly. Now, when I run this in a simulator, it doesn't crop the images.

[image]

As you can see the images bleed above and below the UIView.

FYI the images have an opacity of `0.35`.

How do I get the images to properly crop to the UIView border?

Comment: set clipToBounds = true for UIImageView also.

Comment: Rob, why your UIIMageView is taller than UIView if you want that to be bounded inside UIView. Just  fit it inside View and set set clipToBounds = true for your UIImageView.

Comment: @AshokPolu tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @ankit I want the uiImageview to be inside the uiView, but it's going to be taller than the UIView. So, the little extra bit that will bleed out of the UIView, I want to not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using constraints then add height constraints to image view and then try.

In your case, its flexible, so uitableViewCell taking the height of image inside imageview.

Comment: I want the uitableViewCell to stay the same size. I want the uiImageView to keep the same ratio. If it stretches to the same height, then the image will be distorted.

Comment: In that case, instead of constant height, you can use aspect ratio.

Comment: Yes, but then the image won't fit to the sides

Comment: please share screenshot after adding height constrain, may be you need to try different contentMode.

Answer (score 0):

Set UIImageView attribute,
     `clipsToBounds = true`

not just the parent UIView. They have different attributes even the UIImageView is a child of your UIView.